# content section of a webpage changing while header and footer stay the same - Cannot get code sample working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using the code sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079618/how-can-we-change-only-inner-part-of-a-web-page) (as well as W3Schools), I am trying to learn how to build a web-page with unchanging header, nav (left margin), and footer pieces, with a section in the middle that changes based on what's clicked.

My main page (test01.html):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                 $("#activities").click(function(){
                     $("#body").load("test02.html");
                 });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <a href="#" id="#activities">Activities</a>
            <!-- this stays the same -->
        </div>
        <div id="body">

            <!-- All content will be loaded here dynamically -->

        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <!-- this stays the same -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My content that should be displayed when "Activities" is clicked (test02.html):

```html
<p>---</p>
<p>Hello world!</p>
<p>---</p>
```

When I click "Activities" the url (in the address bar changes to "test01.html#" but the contents of test02.html does not load.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the developer console.

Comment: In your HTML, the ID of the link is "#activities" but should be "activities". See [MDN's ID global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and [jQuery's ID Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

Comment: @showdev  -  Wow.  thank you!

Comment: @epascarello  -  What is that (developer console)?  How do I look at it?